# NoHttpResponseException is a retriable exception?

Tags: connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

We implemented connection pooling in our client code to invoke a server which closes(sends Connection:close in response headers) a connection after 2.5mins. Due to server behaviour we sometimes/intermittently get NoHttpResponseException. And this may occur at high TPS or at low TPS as well.

We are using apache http client version 4.5.11. And there is one `validateAfterInactivity` setting in `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` which is by-default set to 2000ms. But i think we may get same exception if we try to get the connection in 2000ms period.

We can choose to set aggressive value for validateAfterInactivity but i heard that it can degrade the performance by ~20 to 30ms for each request.

is retrying this exception a good solution ?

And also align to same context, can we retry in case of **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset** ?

@ok2c any suggestion here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`NoHttpResponseException` is considered safe to retry for idempotent methods.

In your particular case however I would consider limiting the TTL (total to live) of client connections to 2.5 minutes to match that of the server endpoints.

Comment: In my case it is post method. And server can close the connection based on multiple factors like maxKeepAliveRequests=15 or keepAliveTimeout=20000. because of this i don't think setting ttl would be right thing.  why it is not recommended to retry for POST method. And what about java.net.SocketException: Connection reset ?

Comment: TTL and keep-alive parameters are not mutually exclusive. The client would still properly react to standard keep-alive response parameters but it would just not re-use connections beyond their TTL.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. But we don't want to depend on server, tomorrow they may remove this configuration(2.5min and other). And from client side we don't want to close a connection until it is not idle. If NoHttpResponseException can't be retried what your suggestion for java.net.SocketException: Connection reset ?  can we retry this ?